# Instantiating a struct yields "cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers"

Tags: swift, struct

## The problem

I have the following struct that represents an RGBA pixel. I would like to instantiate it to create a Pixel object of my own but I'm failing to do so. The compiler is throwing this error `'Pixel' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

## What I tried

For example, all these return the same error:

```
var myPixel = Pixel()
var myPixel = Pixel(value: UInt32(1))
var myPixel = Pixel(value: UInt32(1), red: UInt8(1), green: UInt8(1), blue: UInt8(1))
```

## The struct in question

```
public struct Pixel {
    public var value: UInt32

    public var red: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8(value & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = UInt32(newValue) | (value & 0xFFFFFF00)
        }
    }

    public var green: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 8) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 8) | (value & 0xFFFF00FF)
        }
    }

    public var blue: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 16) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 16) | (value & 0xFF00FFFF)
        }
    }

    public var alpha: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 24) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 24) | (value & 0x00FFFFFF)
        }
    }
}
```

## How other people use it in the same code base

I cannot change the struct as it is being used someplace else and it is definitely working. I've dug through the code where they use it in a Pixel array but cannot make heads or tails of it (first time using Swift). Here's what I think are the relevant bits:

```
public struct RGBAImage {
    public var pixels: [Pixel]
    // ...    
    public init?(image: UIImage) {
        // ...
        let imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>.alloc(width * height)
        // ...
        let bufferPointer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>(start: imageData, count: width * height)
        pixels = Array(bufferPointer)
        // ...
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

I'm using a Swift Playground and the `Pixel` struct and `RGBAImage` struct are in a separate file in the Sources folder. The code that is not working is in the main playground page. If I copy/paste the `Pixel` struct to the main page, everything works as expected.

Comment: var p = Pixel(value: UInt32(1))
works fine for me.  Perhaps the problem has to do with scope?  Where is the struct definition in the project - and where is your variable declaration?  Also is there some other type called Pixel that could be conflicting?

Comment: `Pixel(value: UInt32(1))` should definitely work, just like simply `Pixel(value: 1)`.

Comment: @Dan I'm using a Swift playground and the struct is in a file in the Resources folder. If I paste the struct in the main file, it works as intended. This is odd since I'm using the `RGBAImage` class in the same file without including it or doing anything special. Something to do with scopes in the playground like you suggested...